# How to write behavioral/functional/endpoint tests using Angular and Jasmine + $resource?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, functional-testing, angular-mock

I want to write functional test of the server's endpoints. I'm not doing e2e testing. This is more of a functional/behavioral test.

```
    beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {
        f = $injector.get('WidgetFactory');
    }));

    it('should have a factory and get all widgets',inject(function($timeout ){
       expect(f).toBeDefined();
       expect(f).toBeTruthy();

       var qArray = f.query();

       $timeout.flush()

       expect(qArray.length).toBe(3);
    }));
```

However, jasmine produces this error:

```
unexpected request: GET http://some.made.up.service:8080/widget/ 
No more request expected
```

I **do not** want to mock it with `httpBackend.whenGET()`, I want to actually test my endpoint for undesired behavior (AKA blame the backend team). My unit tests that mock the response are a separate spec file.

Any way to do this with jasmine? I'd like to not also have to add protractor or mocha.

Answer (score 0):

So I guess you looking for api endpoint test frameworks. Frisby ( http://frisbyjs.com/docs/api/ ) is a good fit for that. Its built on nodejs and jasmine to test endpoints.